# GXT 3.x Custom PropertyEditor / ValueBaseInputCell

Tags: editor, gxt, propertyeditor

I'm trying to write a **custom field editor** that will translate between **Long** and **String**. IE: String representation on screen but field type is a Long.

I've implemented the PropertyEditor ([HrMinPropertyEditor](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/gwt/src/main/java/biz/freshcode/learn/gwt/client/experiment/forms/HrMinPropertyEditor.java)) but don't know how to wire it in. My [HrMinField](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/gwt/src/main/java/biz/freshcode/learn/gwt/client/experiment/forms/HrMinField.java) is quite clunky as I needed to use a TriggerFieldCell because the generic types inside TextInputCell etc. prevented me from using them.

**Do I need to do a subclass of ValueBaseInputCell?** That seems strange since my PropertyEditor has all the Long / String conversions. It also looks difficult.

If so, is there a **simple example or some documentation** I can read?

BTW, my learning project is Maven based and should be easy to fire up if necessary:

1. svn checkout http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/freshcode_public/learn/gwt/ learn-gwt
2. cd learn-gwt
3. mvn gwt:run
4. Navigate to **GXT | Forms | Time Edit**

Thanks in advance,

Pete

PS: I've asked this on the [Sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196775) too.

Answer (score 1):

You should use method **setPropertyEditor** from **Field** class to specify your custom property editor:

```
HrMinField f = new HrMinField();
f.setPropertyEditor( new HrMinPropertyEditor() );
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with a solution using a Converter and a Validator.

The [more complete answer](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196775-Custom-PropertyEditor-ValueBaseInputCell#post786832) is on the [Sencha thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196775).